# Customising Google Chrome web browser in Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On the google theme store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes you have themes that have not just the tabs but search bar etc. with background images, transparent not just the colour that is allowed when creating your own theme.

Q: Is there a file that I can edit like a CSS file attached to my chrome browser or any other way that I can customise my chrome browser.

Change the colours, add images, font size, highlight of text colours?

Thank you.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide It also looks like it's a json file that controls elements.

Comment: @disinfor I think that's worthy of being an answer.

Comment: Seems the _ThemeCreationGuide_ was removed.  Here is some useful info I found: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes